# problemas de rotas no ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

no arquivo routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    root 'pages#home'
    get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

porém quando digito a URL ele gera problema como na figura abaixo;[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será que digitei algo errado no arquivo **routes**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua rota está ok. O problema exibido parece ser no controller, ou ele não foi definido ou está com nomenclatura diferente. Verifique o nome de seu controller e corrija em sua rota.

caso tenha problemas, edite sua pergunta e coloque seus controllers para ajudar no diagnóstico.

Comment: me desculpe, eu ainda estou aprendendo a programar em Ruby on Rails, eu estou estudando com cursos que não falam em português, é difícil encontrar bons materiais de cursos em Português, mas isso ajudou e resolveu minha dúvida o problema realmente era o controller.

Comment: Não precisa se desculpar @wladyband, esse lugar é exatamente para você tirar dúvidas, você está no caminho certo. Se a resposta te ajudou marque-a como correta (esse "v" abaixo do contador). Precisando estaremos sempre aqui para ajudar. Bons estudos.